# The render result is correct but when in the viewer node the render is going off screen

Tags: rendering, camera, compositing-nodes, resolution

I'm trying to put my render with a background image which worked the first time, but when I enlarged the resolution of the background image in photoshop to twice its size (from 4368 × 2084 to 8736 × 4168) and put it back in blender (and after doubling the size of the render resolution to match) the render is going off screen as shown in the pictures. How do I fix this?

Here's a link to screenshots: https://www.flickr.com/photos/163507419@N03/?

first one shows how I want it to look (this was when it worked at the 4368 × 2084 resolution), the others show what it looks like now

[image][image]
[image][image][image]

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Please use this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgAFv.gif to post screenshots as it will directly embed them and allow you to organize them in your question as well as ensure long term archival instead of an external link that may vanish. Also, if need be, attach your blender file using this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your .blend and image files at hand, I can't tell for sure what is happening.

However, usually **a "*Scale*" node (found under "*Distort*"), set to "*Render Size*" and applied just after the *Image* input**, should guarantee that RenderLayers and external images have matching sizes. (Note: if the image is smaller than the render layers, it will be stretched, losing sharpness in the process)

[image]

I don't know, however, why they don't match already if – as you say – you already changed the resolutions in both the image and Blender. I can just suggest to check again.

Comment: Hi Nicola, I've added the blend file and images now, I'm about to check your method

Comment: Hi Nicola, your suggestion has worked! Thank you for your help

Comment: Hello Kenzo. Glad it worked! However, I've checked your blend file: be aware that you have opened the file "hi rez 2" into blender, but you are still using the original file (Gas station.jpg) in your "Image" node! I don't know what sizes these files are (they aren't packed into the .blend) but you might want to check which one you're supposed to be using!

Comment: Ah yes i forgot to do that as well! thank you for pointing that out too